# How to mount volume mounted in a docker image into another docker image?

Tags: docker

Let's say I have a folder on my system:

```
/foo/bar/project
```

I can mount this into a single docker image using:

```
docker run -v /foo/bar/project:/project
```

and it is now mounted into my docker image. Best practice for running embedded docker images is using the following flag:

```
-v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

This causes docker to use the same daemon for both levels of docker images.

Now I want to mount the same `/foo/bar/project` folder into the nested docker image. One way I can do this is to find where it is mounted into my first docker image through inspect:

```
{
                "Name": "6b0091a538097a400b452997146ff0751079f6b31aa9174171b889aeb2756e59",
                "Source": "/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/6b0091a538097a400b452997146ff0751079f6b31aa9174171b889aeb2756e59/_data",
                "Destination": "/project",
                "Driver": "local",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": ""
            }
```

this allows me to mount the docker "host" project folder by adding:

```
-v /mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/volumes/6b0091a538097a400b452997146ff0751079f6b31aa9174171b889aeb2756e59/_data:/project
```

I have not been able to find a different way to mount the /foo/bar/project --> /project -->  other than this.

Is there a more straightforward way to do this? That hash changes each time the outside container is created, which means I will have to determine the `-v` flag during runtime. This is not horribly complex for my current application where I already have a docker wrapper but feels *very* hacky.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by saying "nested docker image", are you running docker container inside docker container?

Comment: @rm-rf yes, that is what I mean